# Shell script- reason for using bin/echo instead of echo?

Tags: shell, unix

I have a shell script from 2011, the purpose of which is to run on different unix systems.

The script defines certain variables and I don't understand the logic behind it, I would like to know why is this done so. For example:
instead of using `echo` or `grep` directly in the script, these variables are defined as follows:
`ECHO="/bin/echo"`
`GREP="/bin/grep"` (for linux)
for Solaris or other ,  the corresponding path is defined as well.
They are then used as `${ECHO} "something out"`

What is the purpose of this practice and why can I not use it directly?

Comment: Trusting random chunks of shell you find somewhere to be reasonable or sensical is not good practice. There's **lots** of cargo-cult programming in shell... which, if you copy random things you see in other peoples' scripts, you might end up participating in yourself.

Comment: BTW, this would be `/bin/echo`, not `bin\echo`.

Comment: @JimLewis, that was referring to the purpose of the script, not the purpose of the practice. I rather emphatically hold that the practice in question damages, rather than enhances, portability.

Comment: BTW, as an extra piece of evidence that the script you're looking at was written by someone who didn't particularly have a great hold on what they were doing -- all-caps names are in a space that POSIX sets aside for variable names with meaning to the shell or operating system. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, keeping in mind that shell and environment variables share a namespace.

Comment: @Charles Duffy finding out what good practice is, is the exact point of this question since I am a beginner. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy:  your comments about uppercase variable names are of course correct.  Back in the late '70s and early '80s a lot of newbie UNIX people came from mainframes that only had uppercase, so they carried the practice across.  Back then there were fewer variables used by the shell, and of course no POSIX.  Its my belief that the example has survived through the years by no one questioning their old UNIX 'guru'.  So kudos to the OP for finally asking why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have pointed out, it is unlikely that those lines are correct, more likely they should be:

```
ECHO="/bin/echo"
GREP="/bin/grep"  # (for linux)
```

Assuming that they are correct, code like this used to be commonly seen in shell scripts (not mine, I might add).  You don't see many people using these any more.

`echo`:  `ksh` (Korn shell, which used to be the shell of choice), `csh` (C-shell, default shell on Sun) and `sh` (Bourne shell before it was POSIX) all had their own built-in versions of `echo` that were slightly different (mostly around the `-n` argument).  Therefore the stand-alone program `/bin/echo` was sometimes used for portability.  There is a performance price to pay for that.

`grep` and others:  It used to be commonly recommended that the full path name for external programs should be set in a script.  The main reason was security.  In theory a user could provide their own version in a local directory and change their `PATH` variable.  `PATH`, and all other environment variables, is still considered a security risk by many.  A secondary reason was the performance overhead of searching the directories of `$PATH` - this was before the days of tracked aliases (ksh) or hashing (bash).

I'll repeat that I don't subscribe to all these views, and I have had arguments over the years with those who do, however that is the explanation.  In my opinion this practice causes more problems than it solves.

EDIT:  the practices I mention go back to the 1970s and 80s.  Why would they be in a script from 2011?  Possibly because "we always do that", a.k.a. "company policy", i.e. no one knows or cares why, we just do.  Alternatively it could be a case of copy n'paste from an old web-site or book, or even someone who believes this is a good idea.

Comment: I ran in a problem where using `/bin/echo` makes sense as of today. Builtin `echo` seems to treat embedded backslash escapes differently according to the shell versions. The only reliable way I found to use POSIX' `-E` switch is by using the binary version.

Answer (score 3):

There is no good reason **whatsoever** for this practice.

It reduces scripts' portability (by requiring modification when moving to any system with different binary locations), reduces performance (by suppressing use of shell builtins where available), and (as PATH lookups are cached) does not significantly improve runtime performance by saving lookup costs.

---

One caveat: On some systems, `/bin/` is not the canonical location for POSIX tools; for instance, `/usr/xpg/bin/sh` would be the location for POSIX sh, and `/usr/xpg/bin/awk` would be the location for POSIX awk, on some ancient SunOS systems.

The wrong way to enforce use of POSIX-compliant tools on such a system is to hardcode these paths in variables defined at the top of the script.

The right way to enforce use of POSIX-compliant tools on such a system is simply to specify a PATH that puts `/usr/xpg/bin` before `/bin`. For instance, a script can specify `[ -d /usr/xpg/bin ] && PATH=/usr/xpg/bin:$PATH`, and serve this purpose thus.

---

Alternately, assume that one wishes to use GNU find. Instead of setting a `FIND` variable at the top of a script, one can specify a wrapper as needed, falling through to the default behavior of using the standard `find` command if no renamed alternative exists:

```
# use GNU find if under a name other than "find"
if type gnufind >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  find() { gnufind "$@"; }
elif type gfind >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  find() { gfind "$@"; }
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Limiting this answer the `echo` part.

Probably this was an attempt to make the program portable, but it was a futile one.

The `echo` command itself is always unportable if the arguments can contain a backslash or the first argument is `-n`. POSIX says in these cases the behavior will be implementation-dependent.

Source: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/echo-invocation.html#echo-invocation

Both `dash` and `bash` claim POSIX compliance, but `echo 'a\nb'` will lead to a different result. And both are correct. I would not rely on the hope that all stand-alone `echo` programs on the planet just happen to choose the same implementation either.

The easiest way to get the code really portable for any argument is to use `printf` instead of `echo`.

If you really wanted to call the command `echo` instead of the built-in because you are confident that your code will never be run on a system with a different implementation choice `command echo` would be the best way to do it.